# handling multiple IFs in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code on a model, which works, but I'd love to find a way to refactor it to be something a little smaller and neater. I'd also love to only run it under the condition that the state field actually changes. Can someone point me in the right direction. This is rails 3 BTW.

What it does is look at the "state" field on a model called subscription, and if that changes from one condition to another, then makes an update in salesforce. I'm looking for a way to optimise this code.

```
  after_save :update_salesforce

  def update_salesforce
    if self.state_changed? && salesforce_client
      salesforce_client.materialize("Opportunity")

      o = Opportunity.find_by_breatheHR_id__c(self.subscriber_id)
      if o
        old_state = self.state_was
        new_state = self.state
        #update salesforce when accounts go active
        if (old_state =='trial' || old_state == 'suspended') && new_state =='active'
          o.update_attribute(:Stage__c, "Active Account")
        end
        #update salesforce when accounts go active
        if old_state =='trial' && new_state =='suspended'
          o.update_attribute(:Stage__c, "Trial Suspended")
        end
        #update salesforce when accounts go active
        if old_state =='active' && new_state =='suspended'
          o.update_attribute(:Stage__c, "Account Suspended")
        end
        #update salesforce when accounts go active
        if old_state =='active' && new_state =='inactive'
          o.update_attribute(:Stage__c, "Account Cancelled")
        end
        #update salesforce when accounts go active
        if old_state =='trial' && new_state =='inactive'
          o.update_attribute(:Stage__c, "Trial Cancelled")
        end
      end_of_day
    end
  end
```

In terms of only running it, I tried

```
after_save :update_salesforce, :if => self.state_changed?
```

but it doesn't recognise "self" at this point.

Comment: `:if => self.state_changed?`: The ruby code is evaluated and executed when this part is read, you need to use a Lambda/Proc in the if in order to "store" the logic and not execute it: `if: Proc.new{ self.state_changed? }`

Comment: I'd definitely consider using a state machine gem in this situation. Either AASM or state_machine. https://github.com/aasm/aasm or https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine. It allows you to define allowed transitions and add hooks to them.

Comment: What is `end_of_day`? Just a typo?

Answer (score 2):

Here are several refactorings that you can apply:

#### Remove unnecessary `self`

You don't need to write `self` every time, only when *setting* values, because otherwise Ruby will create a local variable instead of calling the setter method. In your case, all occurrences of `self` are superfluous and just add noise.

#### Flatten nested conditionals

You need to get rid of unnecessary nesting, it makes the code much easier to read and understand. Generally speaking, you can return early when preconditions fail. For example:

```
def update_salesforce
  if state_changed? && salesforce_client
    o = Opportunity.find_by_breatheHR_id__c(subscriber_id)
    if o
      # perform hard work
    end
  end
end

# becomes

def update_salesforce
  return unless state_changed? && salesforce_client

  o = Opportunity.find_by_breatheHR_id__c(subscriber_id)
  return unless o

  # perform hard work
end
```

#### Use ActiveRecord's `:if` option

In the special case of the check whether the state has changed, you can use the `:if` option on the `after_save` callback. You were very close, but you either need to supply the method name as symbol, or use a proc. For a simple situation like this one, you can use the symbol form:

```
after_save :update_salesforce, :if => :state_changed?
```

#### Use statement modifiers

The other case is also special in that you can tack the `return` at the end of the line with a statement modifier `or`. This is actually the intended use of `or`, whereas you should always use `||` for boolean operations. The transformation is

```
x = do_something
return unless x

# becomes

x = do_something or return
```

#### Replace repetitive conditionals with hash access

When you look at the method, most lines repeat over and over again with only slight variation. What you can do about this is to extract the state transition logic into a separate method. In this method you can pull off a trick and put the varying states into a hash, from which you select the appropriate value. The keys are arrays representing the transition, and the values are the new values for the `Stage__c` field. When `nil` is returned, `Stage__c` must not be updated. For example:

```
def new_stage_from_state_transition(old_state, new_state)
  {
    ['suspended', 'active'   ] => 'Active Account',
    ['trial'    , 'active'   ] => 'Active Account',
    ['trial'    , 'suspended'] => 'Trial Suspended',
    ['active'   , 'suspended'] => 'Account Suspended',
    ['active'   , 'inactive' ] => 'Account Cancelled',
    ['trial'    , 'inactive' ] => 'Trial Cancelled'
  }[[old_state, new_state]]
end
```

#### Put everything together

All of this results in much cleaner and less repetitive code:

```
after_save :update_salesforce, :if => :state_changed?

def update_salesforce
  return unless salesforce_client
  o = Opportunity.find_by_breatheHR_id__c(subscriber_id) or return
  new_stage = new_stage_from_state_transition(state_was, state) or return
  o.update_attribute(:Stage__c, new_stage)
end

def new_stage_from_state_transition(old_state, new_state)
  {
    ['suspended', 'active'   ] => 'Active Account',
    ['trial'    , 'active'   ] => 'Active Account',
    ['trial'    , 'suspended'] => 'Trial Suspended',
    ['active'   , 'suspended'] => 'Account Suspended',
    ['active'   , 'inactive' ] => 'Account Cancelled',
    ['trial'    , 'inactive' ] => 'Trial Cancelled'
  }[[old_state, new_state]]
end
```

Comment: Superb answer. I can't check it until the morning unfortunately. what's the asterix doing in "*transition"?

Comment: Ah sorry, I actually wanted to remove that. It's the splat operator, basically it takes all the arguments and puts them into an array in the `transition` variable. However it's not necessary here, because the number of arguments is fixed to two and so it only makes things more complicated. Edited and removed the splat.

Comment: Edited again and added another small improvement.

Answer (score 0):

```
#update salesforce when accounts go active
if new_state =='active'
  o.update_attribute(:Stage__c, "Active Account")
else
  what = old_state == 'active' ? "Account" : "Trial"
  change = new_state == 'inactive' ? "Canceled" : "Suspended"
  o.update_attribute(:Stage__c, "#{what} #{change}" )
end
```